Why do we need Kafka Broker / Server / Node ? Why cannot Producers or Consumers interact with each other directly?
I just want to know adding a broker between Consumer and Producer solves which problem
I could not find any answers
This is all I know -
The Kafka broker is used for managing the storage of the data records/messages in the topic. It can be simply understood as the mediator between the two. We define a Kafka cluster when there is more than one broker present. The Kafka broker is responsible for transferring the conversation that the publisher is pushing in the Kafka log commit and the subscriber shall be consuming these messages. The conversation is mediated between the multiple systems, enabling the delivery of the data records/ message to process to the right consumer.

In a system without a broker, how does a producer know the consumers to talk to?

A producer can directly send or create connection with Consumer , they can talk with each other , Like a phone call

What if no consumer is available for a producer to send to? Kafka storage is persistent and distributed.
Many consumers are able to read any one record sent by a producer in a poll model. If you want a push model, use plain sockets, HTTP, gRPC, etc rather than a message broker

@SamPa: how does that producer know where the consumers are?
